# Jquery .once() issue with Drupal 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

Recently I configured FullCalendar v3 with my Drupal 8 project, it works fine and all feature applied.

The issue is something do with with JQUERY 3.3.1 that I imported as configuration with FullCalendar.

When I ignore this Jquery to load the issue will fix but FullCalendar will not work anymore.

I got these errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).once is not a function
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Bridge' of undefined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).once is not a function

I search for these errors and try the best match result but not fixed yet.
I change to other jquery, activate the main theme instead of sub-theme, but not result.

This is my module library.yml

```
amt_scripts:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      assets/css/bootstrap.min.css: {}
      assets/css/fullcalendar.css: {}
      assets/css/amt_dayview.css: {}
  js:
    # assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.js: {}
    assets/js/jquery.min.js: {}
    assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js: {}
    assets/js/bootstrap.min.js: {}
    assets/js/moment.min.js: {}
    assets/js/fullcalendar.min.js: {}
    assets/js/scheduler.min.js: {}
    assets/js/popper.min.js: {}
    assets/js/amt_dayview.js: {}
  dependencies:
```

The Image of Batrik theme:
[image]

Comment: I can't see that this has much, if anything, to do with fullCalendar directly: https://www.google.com/search?q=%24(...).once+is+not+a+function+&client=ms-android-google&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8 . Have you looked into any of the many existing resources discussing this error?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned I check most of them like change Jquery version, remove it but not working.

Comment: Most of the answers I read seemed to be talking about problems with the bootstrap theme file, not jQuery. .once() is not a core jQuery method

Comment: I don't Agree, I just change to a drupal theme like Batrik, and the issue happens for that as well, you can see the image of result in the question I added now. @ADyson

Comment: Well it's still a fact that .once() is not a core jQuery method, or is it anything related to fullCalendar. It's something related to Drupal. Your issue was not (directly) caused by installing fullCalendar, more a case of things it depends on. It appears, according to https://sqndr.github.io/d8-theming-guide/javascript/behaviors.html that you need to ensure you have a reference to a Drupal-related file in order for it to work

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/244492/jquery-once-onload also mentions it being a Drupal-created function. And here as well https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use dependencies like this and add jquery from Drupal core

```
amt_scripts:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      assets/css/fullcalendar.css: {}
  js:
    assets/js/popper.min.js: {}
    assets/js/bootstrap.min.js: {}
    assets/js/moment.min.js: {}
    assets/js/fullcalendar.min.js: {}
    assets/js/scheduler.min.js: {}
    assets/js/amt_dayview.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery-ui
```

but this approach will work with hook_page_attachments ,to add library:

**ISSUE** this method will add the library to all page but I want it on the specific page that needs to check it with the current path.

```
/**
 * Implemets hook_page_attachments().
 */
function amt_dayview_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  // Attach dayview Script just working fine with this hook.
  // But it is need to load just for dayview page.
  if (\Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath() == '/day-view') {
    // Unconditionally attach an asset to the page.
    $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'amt_dayview/amt_scripts';    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you added dependencies like

```
dependencies:
- core/jquery
- core/drupal.ajax
- core/drupal
- core/drupalSettings
- core/jquery.once
```

Comment: Yes, I found this and Issue fixed by adding dependency but not just this. I change my attachment hook that loads this to attachment page hook.

Comment: Either way you can by adding it to libraries and attaching library or using hook.